# MySQL compare 2 tables values

Tags: mysql, join

I got a query:

```
SELECT  a.Vendor, i.Vendor
FROM    whole1 a 
        LEFT JOIN whole2 i 
        ON (a.Vendor = i.Vendor) 
GROUP BY a.Vendor, i.Vedor 
LIMIT 0, 200
```

By default Inner JOIN is used. Left join gives me all results from left table. Same with Right join.

What I'm looking for is combination of Left and Right join, However NOT INNER Join.

I want to have a result like

```
AMD, NULL
ACER, NULL
NULL, INTEL
NULL, ATI
```

Any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a  [full outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join),
which is unfortunately not implemented in `MYSQL`, instead you can use `union` of `left` and `right` join :

```
SELECT a.`Vendor`, i.`Vendor`
FROM `whole1` a LEFT JOIN whole2 i ON (a.`Vendor` = i.`Vendor`) 
GROUP BY a.`Vendor`, i.`Vendor` 

UNION

SELECT a.`Vendor`, i.`Vendor`
FROM `whole1` a RIGHT JOIN whole2 i ON (a.`Vendor` = i.`Vendor`) 
GROUP BY a.`Vendor`, i.`Vendor`
```

Comment: @marvin - you can easily add `LIMIT` to each one of selects or to the result of union.

Comment: You will get duplicate rows if a vendor appears in both tables

Comment: @SirRufo - `The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result` - from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: @Grisha I just earned a RTFM badge ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Using union with Left and Right Join and from that a select with the limit

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    a.`Vendor` v1, i.`Vendor` v2
  FROM 
    `whole1` a 
  LEFT JOIN 
    whole2 i ON (a.`Vendor` = i.`Vendor`) 
  GROUP BY 
    a.`Vendor`, i.`Vendor` 

  UNION

  SELECT 
    a.`Vendor`, i.`Vendor`
  FROM 
    `whole1` a 
  RIGHT JOIN 
    whole2 i ON (a.`Vendor` = i.`Vendor`) 
  GROUP BY 
    a.`Vendor`, i.`Vendor`
) AS whole
LIMIT 0,200
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/960f9/2/0)

Comment: You didn't need the outer `DISTINCT`. `UNION` is an implicit distinct. [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/960f9/3)